# How to use external email client in Vtiger?

Tags: vtiger

I use vtiger 7.1 on my Linux server and I want to use my email client (Thunderbird)
I removed check from Settings-> My Preference -> internal email composer

But nothing happened... I still obtain the internal email composer of Vtiger.